# Sending variable to PHP with AJAX, receiving JSON back

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

Using the following jQuery, how can I read through the values of the JSON that's returned? With it how it is, the jQuery doesn't even run as there is an error in: `alert("A" + obj.sender[0]);`

```
var session_id = $(this).find(".session_id").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../php/read.php',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {sesh_id: session_id},
        success: function (response) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            alert("A" + obj.sender[0]);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Err: " + response.status);
        }
    });
```

The value of response is:

```
[{
    "sender":"email@example.com",
    "details":"details1",
    "date":"2017-01-04 16:11:04"
},
{
    "sender":"someone@example.com",
    "details":"details2",
    "date":"2017-01-04 16:11:05"
},
{
    "sender":"blah@example.com",
    "details":"details3",
    "date":"2017-01-04 16:11:06"
}]
```

Comment: What is the error you get back?

Comment: does the URL its posting to actually exist?

Comment: check in inspector if you are getting the answer via javascript and what status code it has... my two guesses: 1. url is not valid in ajax request 2. somehow php returns HTTP 500

Comment: You don't need `var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);`. Btw, you _still_ need to add the actual error messages!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Updated question, previous question was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that your index accessor is in the wrong place as `obj` is an array, not the `sender` property, so it should be `obj[0].sender`.

You also don't need to call `JSON.parse()` on the response, as jQuery does that for you automatically as you specified `dataType: 'json'`. Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../php/read.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { sesh_id: session_id },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("A" + obj[0].sender);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log("Err: " + response.status);
    }
});
```

Finally, note that `console.log()` is much more preferable when debugging over `alert()` as it doesn't coerce data types.